# Possible differences between two databases with different sizes but same set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have updated two databases in MSSQL Server 2008R2 using liquibase.
Both of them start with the same database, but one ran through several liquibase updates until the final one incrementally, the other just go straight to the final update.

So I have checked they have the same schema, same set of data, but their .mdf file sizes are 10GB apart.

What areas (best to provide also the SQL command) I can look into to investigate what possibly gives me this 10GB difference (e.g. Index? Unused empty spaces? etc...)

I am not trying to make them the same (so no Shrink), I just want to find out the places that contribute to this 10GB size difference. So I will accept answers like using HEX editor to open up the mdf files and compare byte by byte, but I need to know what am I looking at.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The internal structure (physical organization, not logical data) of databases is opaque both by design and due to the real-world scenarios that affect how data is created, updated and accessed.

In most cases there is literally no telling why two logically equivalent databases are different on a physical level. It is some combination of deleted objects, unbalanced pages, disk-based temporary tables, history of garbage collection, and many other potential causes.

In short, you would never expect a physical database to be 1:1 with the logical data it contains.

Comment: For those things you mentioned, if you can provide commands for me to pull those information out I can accept your answer.

Comment: If you had logging turned on during these operations, the log files will show you a sequence of operations performed.  I'll recommend two approaches: (1) review the transactions logs for each DB using the `DBCC LOG` command, or (2) if you prefer a more "baked" solution, use a tool like ApexSQL to view the log in a more human-readable fashion.